# HTML code getting changed in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have following code inside javascript loop

```
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<form action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"id\" value="+id+" hidden><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"contact\" value="+contact+"><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"add\" value="+add+" ><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"city\" value="+city+" ><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"zip\" value="+zip+" ><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"state\" value="+state+" ><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit Address\"><br>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="</form>";
```

but when i check in browser the ending form tag gets appended at the end of form tag (see first line below) because of this my submit button is not working please help me figure out what's the problem.

in my browser's elements tab it shows like below

```
<form action="updateUserInfo" method="POST"></form>
<input type="text" name="id" value="1" hidden=""><br>
<input type="text" name="contact" value="ijkl"><br>
<input type="text" name="add" value="abcd"><br>
<input type="text" name="city" value="efgh"><br>
<input type="text" name="zip" value="xyza"><br>
<input type="text" name="state" value="mnop"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Edit Address"><br>
```

Comment: Why don't you add all at once? :)

Comment: Each time you write to `innerHTML` the browser will parse the code right away. You're writing an unclosed form tag which the browser closes automatically. You need to put all your code in a string and then write that string to `innerHTML` in a single operation.

Comment: because it makes the line too long and i have to scroll frequently when i need to change something can you please explain the unexpected behaviour in browser

Comment: ok thanks @MikaelLennholm

Comment: Try template literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser will try to fix invalid HTML, which means, among others, closing unclosed tags. Note that your first line:

```
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML+="<form action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">";
```

creates invalid code. The browser will immediately close that tag for you.

If you want it to behave correctly, build the whole HTML string and do a single `innerHTML` assignment instead:

```
const html = "<form action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"id\" value="+id+" hidden><br>"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"contact\" value="+contact+"><br>"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"add\" value="+add+" ><br>"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"city\" value="+city+" ><br>"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"zip\" value="+zip+" ><br>"
    + "<input type=\"text\" name = \"state\" value="+state+" ><br>"
    + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit Address\"><br>"
    + "</form>";
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML += html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mayby start autosacrifice tag. Try to save in string variable and than innerHtml this value.

```js
var block = document.getElementById("alladdress");
var str = '';
var id = 1, contact = 'default', add='true', city = 'NY', zip = 'true', state = '-';

str+="<form action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"id\" value="+id+" hidden><br>";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"contact\" value="+contact+"><br>";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"add\" value="+add+" ><br>";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"city\" value="+city+" ><br>";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"zip\" value="+zip+" ><br>";
str+="<input type=\"text\" name = \"state\" value="+state+" ><br>";
str+="<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit Address\"><br>";
str+="</form>";
block.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="alladdress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because browser by itself will try to balance the tags.

Alternatively you can create the template using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML += "<form 
action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">";
```

```html
<div id="alladdress"></div>
```

```js
var id = 'testId';
var contact = 'contact';


document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML = `<form action="updateUserInfo" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name ="${id}" value="+${id}+" hidden><br>
 <input type="text" name = "contact" value="+${contact}+"><br>
</form>`;
```

```html
<div id="alladdress"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding each line seperatly the browser tries to fix your code. I recommend using [template-strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), so you don´t have to struggle with escaping characters and appending all with one variable.

```
const html = `
<form action="updateUserInfo" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="${id}" hidden><br>
    <input type="text" name="contact" value="${contact}"><br>
    ....
</form>
document.getElementById('alladdress').innerHTML += html;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also drop each line into an array and join them in the end.

```js
var id=34,contact="Tom",add="asdf",city="NY",zip="12356",state="NY";
var form = Array();
form[0]="<form action=\"updateUserInfo\" method=\"POST\">";
form[1]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"id\" value="+id+" hidden>";
form[2]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"contact\" value="+contact+">";
form[3]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"add\" value="+add+" >";
form[4]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"city\" value="+city+" >";
form[5]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"zip\" value="+zip+" >";
form[6]="<input type=\"text\" name = \"state\" value="+state+">";
form[7]="<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Edit Address\">";
form[8]="</form>";

document.getElementById("alladdress").innerHTML = form.join('<br>',form);
```

```html
<div id="alladdress">

</div>
```